# How to use Zotero and Vancouver style citations?

Tags: bibliographies, zotero

I'm using Zotero to handle my references and with a plugin called AutoZotBib it generates the following .bib file:

```
@misc{_gps.gov:_2015,
    title = {{GPS}.gov: {GPS} {Accuracy}},
    url = {http://www.gps.gov/systems/gps/performance/accuracy/},
    urldate = {2015-05-07},
    month = may,
    year = {2015},
    annote = {Accessed 3rd July 2008},
    file = {GPS.gov\: GPS Accuracy:C\:\\Users\\marcus.utter\\AppData\\Roaming\\Zotero\\Zotero\\Profiles\\4aig9qvw.default\\zotero\\storage\\X7ZXRNSW\\accuracy.html:text/html}
}
```

I want to show my bibliography in Vancouver style, and attempt to do so by doing the following:

```
\cite{_gps.gov:_2015}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{vancouver}
```

The generated bibliography item looks is:

GPS.gov: GPS Accuracy; 2015. Available from: http://www.gps.gov/
systems/gps/performance/accuracy/.

Which is near, but I also want to show when the resource was accessed. How can this be done?

Comment: Do you have the ability to change the field name from `annote` to `note`?

Comment: That's what I want to do, but the notes added in Zotero shows up under the field called annote

Comment: you'll want to lowercase "accuracy" in the title in Zotero so that it doesn't get enclosed in brackets in bibtex and gets properly lowercased in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I wrote the accessed date in the "extra" field in Zotero instead of adding it in a note and it worked just fine!